# Internet Explorer 8 now running code showing in view source

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a server control that is at the bottom of my page:

```
<%= addPopup() %>
```

Here is the code for it:

```
protected String addPopup()
{
    if (usedSearch == false)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return "<body id=\"test\" onload=\"popup.show()\" runat=\"server\">";
    }
}
```

Basically, depending on what the user does, usedSearch will be true or false, resulting in the HTML line being added to the page:

```
<body onload="popup.show()" runat="server">
```

What this does is show a popup to the user, I do this so that it shows on postback when needed.

This works in all major modern browsers. It does not work in Internet Explorer 8 even though it is showing up in the code behind for every browser including IE8. How do I get IE8 to show the popup when  is part of the page source?

Comment: Is it OK to have two BODY tags??  Do a jQuery document ready script tag instead.

Comment: It seems like that code might return either too many or too little <body> tags.

Comment: You are right, I am incorrectly using 2 body tags. Div does not work in any browser however. How can I make this work without another Body tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering duplicated body tag, probably that's the reason why IE does not pick it up. You should rather output javascript snippet at the bottom of your page, before `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('load', popup.show, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent('onload', popup.show );
    }
</script>
```

It would attach your function to onLoad event in all browsers.

P.S. Just make sure that your popup.show function is initialized before this code.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. However when I output this code instead I am still not getting a popup.

Comment: I guess you output something wrong. Eventually this code snippet should be visible in the browser's page source view. Check javascript errors, etc...